# jQuery waypoints issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-waypoints

I've been having problems with this for days now and it seems like I've spent the last 24 hours staring at the screen scratching my head to find a solution. I think I'm almost there with the code, I just need the div to return to normal (fade back in) when not in the waypoint and it's in the test-border waypoint.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#working-with-us').waypoint(function(direction) {
        if (direction === 'down') {
            $('.nav-container').fadeOut();
        }
        else {
            $('.nav-container').fadeOut();
        }
    });

    $('#contact-us').waypoint(function(direction) {
        if (direction === 'down') {
            $('.nav-container').fadeOut();
        }
        else  {
            $('.nav-container').fadeOut();
        }
    });

    $(".test-border").waypoint(function () {
        $('.nav-container').fadeIn();
    });
});
```

The test border div is in between the two sections. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle example?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8AXUH/2/ I basically need the nav bar to be seen in orange/green (fadeIn) but fadeOut during red/purple sections. Thanks

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/hBLkd/1/

Comment: I think I have tried that before, it doesn't seem to be correct when scrolling back up. Thanks though :)

Comment: Got this working Edward, just in case you fancy a look. http://jsfiddle.net/8AXUH/3/ ... My only issue now is that I want it to fadeOut when going over an image which is in my header.

Comment: I'm posting the same answer yesterday :) can I help you with the last issue?

Comment: Hi Edward, please check out my site involutionstudios.net and you will see the logo. I'm trying to make the nav bar fadeOut when it crosses it up and down. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I may have sorted it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#sectionone, #sectiontwo').waypoint(function (direction) {
    if (direction === 'down') {
        if ($('.nav-container').is(":visible")) $('.nav-container').fadeOut(200);
    } else {
        if (!$('.nav-container').is(":visible")) $('.nav-container').fadeIn(200);
    }
});




$("header, .test-border").waypoint(function (direction) {
    if (direction === 'up') {
        if ($('.nav-container').is(":visible")) $('.nav-container').fadeOut(200);
    } else {
        if (!$('.nav-container').is(":visible")) $('.nav-container').fadeIn(200);
    }
});

});
```